# Did my question get deleted?

Tags: support, scope, specific-question, deleted-questions

I think I had a question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/is-it-still-possible-to-separate-work-from-home-life-with-gmail-etc-how-do-you-d but that now doesn't resolve and I can't find my question anymore. So I'll assume it got deleted. So...questions:

1) No notification of deletion?

If my question was OT, wouldn't it be good to know that?

2) What exactly was wrong with it anyway?

It was a serious question: can you separate two contexts within a web app such as Gmail - or how do people approach this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The question was closed as off topic on October 11th. Without further revisions, the question was deleted a month later. The comments discussing the closing of the question are pretty self explanatory:

> > A discussion of how to maintain work/life balance is rather off-topic for this site.
>
> > This is off topic for this site. A better place would be programmers.stackexchange.com.

Your question seemed to be more about how to keep your online work and home life separate, rather than really needing any sort of technical solution for using an online application.

Whether you agree or not, you are *WAY* more likely to gain the benefits of personal experience by posting your question to the [Programmers Stack Exchange site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). That site is more about *"how do you deal with your technical life"* issues. You would likely get better, more relevant answers there.

*Note: I can still see the (deleted) question. As the question owner, I thought you would be able to see your deleted message, too. Perhaps not.*

Comment: Cool. Well, without being able to see my original question, it's a bit hard to meaningfully discuss whether it was in scope or not.

Comment: can you show that it was deleted?

Comment: I'm not so sure that the advice to post to [programmers.se] is appropriate any more. That site has changed its focus since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the question's text, if you need it:

> For people who have IT-related jobs, and IT-related hobbies (eg, programming, openstreetmap...), how do you keep them separate? I find I use my gmail account for both, I just have one twitter account (which I'm afraid to post anything non-work related on), one stackoverflow account...
>
> If you keep everything in double, don't you get sick of having to set all your preferences twice, have two sets of friends etc?
>
> If you only have one of everything, don't you get sick of your work following you home, reading work-related emails, coming across questions on stackoverflow that you asked while at work...?
>
> I'm really curious what people do.

I think the original poster should be able to view their deleted questions. Were you logged in to the main site when you followed that link? If you were, I would consider it a bug with the system. The SO team might disagree though.

Comment: Thanks for reposting. Re-reading it, I'm not so sure it's off-topic: "what's the best strategy for distinguishing between personal and professional life across the following webpps: ..."

But anyway. Yes, I'm logged into webapps, and can't read my text. I get a "page not found" error when following the link above.

Comment: where did you get the question text?

Comment: @Thufir: Users with high enough reputation can see deleted posts.