# Where are my deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

In relation to:

[Did my question get deleted?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/746/did-my-question-get-deleted)

can I even see where, or if, I have, or might have, closed/deleted/etc. questions?  The answers don't explain how or where information on the question was found.

Answer (score 7):

Go to [your profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/current).

Click the "questions" tab to see your list of questions.

Scroll to the bottom, and click "deleted recent questions".

There you should see the questions that have been deleted "recently". I believe the definition of "recently" here is "within the last 60 days".

More information at

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/21960)
- [What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/21960)